# SSH error between gogs and Jenkins

Tags: ssh, git, jenkins

I am trying to setup an automated pipeline between Jenkins and Gogs and am having some issues with connecting the two together. I feel like I have followed the process correctly but am still receiving a 401 at the end of it.

Here are the steps I have undertaken:

1) Log into my jenkins master server and log into the jenkins user

2) generate a key pair

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "sysadmin@email.ca"
```

3) Added Private key to jenkins under global credentials

4) Added public key to Gogs

5) Go to create a new pipeline, when I enter the repository name I get the following erorr:

```
Help for feature: Repository URL
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://www-git1.mmm.local/git-admin/SF-Firefly-RK3399 HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: error: The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized while accessing https://www-git1.mmm.local/git-admin/SF-Firefly-RK3399/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

UPDATE:

So I am not sure if this will be an issue but I realized that my gogs server and jenkins master are running two different versions of git:

Gogs: git version 1.8.3.1
Jenkins: git version 1.7.1

Could this be the source of my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins understood that you want to use https protocol with git. Maybe you've put `www-git1.mmm.local/git-admin/SF-Firefly-RK3399` and it got converted to `https://www-git1.mmm.local/git-admin/SF-Firefly-RK3399`

As you have generated ssh keys, it maybe best to explicitly set `ssh://username@www-git1.mmm.local/opt/local/absolute/path/to/repo` as your git url.